# Difference between “response.end(data)” and “response.write(data); response.end()”

Tags: node.js, http, safari

I am mystified by a difference that makes a Node.js http server succeed or fails when accessed via the Safari browser.

I narrowed it down to a minimal example with a server that recognizes only two URLs: one that responds with an html page containing an audio element, and one that serves the source for the audio element. The following works fine. When I put it in a file with extension `auserv.mjs`, start it with `node auserv.mjs`, direct the browser to `http://localhost:9999`, and press the play button, the ten second music plays.

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import * as http from 'http';

http.createServer((req, resp) => {
    if (req.url === "/") {
        resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': "text/html" });
        resp.end("<!DOCTYPE html>"+
                 "<title>Play</title>"+
                 "<audio controls>"+
                 "    <source src='ten-second-music.flac' type='audio/flac'>"+
                 "</audio>");
    } else if (req.url === "/ten-second-music.flac") {
        readFile("ten-second-music.flac")
            .then(data => {
                resp.end(data, 'binary');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                resp.statusCode = 500;
                resp.end("<!DOCTYPE html><title>Error</title>Error reading file: "+err);
            });
    } else {
        resp.statusCode = 404;
        resp.end("<!DOCTYPE html><title>Error</title>Not recognized: "+req.url);
    }
}).listen(9999);
```

But if I replace `resp.end(data, 'binary');` with

```
                resp.write(data, 'binary');
                resp.end();
```

it stops working in Safari. No errors turn up at the browser console, it just doesn’t play. (But it still works in Chrome.) What can possibly be the difference? Isn’t it supposed to do the same thing? (In the actual application I can’t send the data in one chunk, so I need it to work with `write`.)

If it’s any clue, it also stops working if I add a `writeHead` like this:

```
                resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'audio/flac' });
                resp.end(data, 'binary');
```

In Safari, that is. This also keeps working in Chrome. It seems to make no difference if I remove the `'binary'` argument from the `end`/`write` call

I am using Mac OS Big Sur. Node.js is v18.12.0, and Safari version is 16.6.1.

**UPDATE** based on comment by Heiko Theißen:

It turns out that it works if a `Content-Length` header is supplied, which it apparently is automatically when sending all the data in just one `end`. The problem is that I am streaming audio, so I can’t say how big the content is going to be. A workaround is to provide an extremely large content length:

```
                resp.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'audio/flac',
                    'Content-Length': 192000*6*60*60*24
                });
                resp.write(data, 'binary');
                // resp.end();
```

(I commented out the `end` to emulate streaming.) This kind of works: Safari displays a spinner for around ten seconds while it’s waiting for more data, then gives up and plays the audio anyway. Not ideal, but I will settle for that unless someone comes up with a better suggestion.

Comment: `resp.write` followed by `resp.end` produces a [chunked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#directives) response, unless you first do `resp.setHeader("Content-Length", ...)`. Perhaps Safari needs this `Content-Length` header or otherwise cannot process chunked audio resources.

Comment: Thanks, @HeikoTheißen, workaround added as update in the post.

Comment: Apparently it works if the `Content-Length` is greater than the actual `data` length. Does it also work if it is less than that? Or are the `data` then cut off?

Comment: I tried setting it to 60, and then it stopped working, even in Chrome.

Comment: Does Safari make [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) when loading the audio file? Perhaps multiple range requests with `206 Partial Content` responses are an alternative to streaming _one_ response?

Comment: No, I don't think there are any range requests. I have decided to give up trying to support Firefox, since there are also a bunch of other quirks that I'm not going to bother handling. Firefox and Chome will have to do.